# DocInteraction with iOS5

Tags: ios, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I found the sample code on Apple website for the DocInteraction project - I am after the QuickLook section for now.

The code is written for an older version than 5.1 which is ok, but it gives me a lot of errors when I want to implement that code.

Does anyone know where i can find a iOS 5.0 version of that code? or a tutorial that explains it?

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a tutorial here:

http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/17/load-a-pdf-file-in-the-iphone-app-smoothly/